# No mapping found

Tags: vim

Starting up vim and then No mapping found shows up at bottom.

running the command: `vim -V20logfile`

```
line 3:   redir => res

line 4:     silent! execute a:cmd

line 5:   redir END

line 6:   let &verbosefile = oldverbosefile
```

Comment: Do you have junk in your ~/.vimrc?

Comment: my .vimrc shows here: https://github.com/kevin4fly/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc

Comment: i think myself that nothing wrong with my vimrc file. to be honest, no side effect so far found. While, it is indeed a issue exist.

Comment: what are you trying to do? `vim -V20logfile` doesn't seem like a valid vim argument

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue.

I commented out all maps, thinking they were all fine. Sure enough, vim loaded without err.

Then, I reintroduced the mappings until one broke it. Sure enough I had left out the space between the lhs and the rhs. As soon as I corrected this, it worked perfectly again.

Comment: The non-breakable space causes this issue, too. I have accidentally introduced one by copying an example.

Answer (score 12):

I found the best way to debug your .vimrc is to enable the debug and pip it to a log file. Examine the file and search for the error.
If the error you are receiving is " no mapping found", open the log file and search for the these words.
:/no mapping found.

It will show you where the error is coming from. In my case I found that the error is from a plugin I installed. I disabled it and it works fine again.

Run the following command at the prompt:

```
vim -V20 2>&1 | tee logfile
```

Comment: This answer is straight to the point. The command snippet avoids all the trial-and-error of re-enabling mappings one by one.